# Get all posts by post_author

Tags: posts, widgets, author, dashboard

I am creating a back-end dashboard where I need to show all the post assigned to **current user** by the wp **admin**.

> I assign user role to **Author** and while creating post (as a wp
>   admin) just assign this post to some author from Author drop-down.

So I need to show posts with status **Publish**. I am now using simple query post but it is returning all posts.

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$user_id = $current_user->ID;    // for current user it is 2

$query = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_author' => $user_id,
        'post_status' => array('publish')
    );
$my_posts = query_posts($query);
```

I also hard-coded **post_author** to 2

I also tried `$my_post = new WP_Query(array( 'post_author' => '2' ));`

but fail.

Answer (score 4):

The shortest possible answer would be to correct 'post_author' to 'author', since that is the [key WP is looking for](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters). If a key is incorrect or misspelled it will be ignored, as was the case with 'post_author'.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Sheikh Heera][1]

```php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ):
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $author_query = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'author' => $current_user->ID
    );
    $author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
    while($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post();
?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php           
    endwhile;
else :

    echo "not logged in";
endif;


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/741747/sheikh-heera
```

Comment: Meh. Somehow I missed that you already had a solution :/

Answer (score 1):

The following mini-plugin adds a dashboard widget that queries posts from the current user that have `publish` as post status. You can see `get_current_user_id()` in use.

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;
/**
 * Plugin Name: (#91605) Dashboard Widget - User posts
 */

add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpse91605_dbwidget_user_posts' );
function wpse91605_dbwidget_user_posts()
{
    wp_add_dashboard_widget(
         'wpse91605_dbwidget_user_posts'
        ,_e( 'Your published posts', 'your_textdomain' )
        ,'wpse91605_dbwidget_user_posts_cb'
    );
}
function wpse91605_dbwidget_user_posts_cb()
{
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
         'author'         => get_current_user_id()
        ,'post_status'    => 'publish'
        ,'posts_per_page' => -1
        ,'showposts'      => -1
        ,'nopaging'       => true
    ) );
    if ( $query->have_posts() )
    {
        ?><ul><?php
        while( $query->have_posts )
        {
            the_post();
            ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a></li>
            <?php
        }
        ?></ul><?php
    }
}
```